# I want to generate list of called functions from a c source file

Tags: ctags

```
ctags -x --c-kinds=f *.c
```

will give me functions *defined* in these C files.

But I want instead just the functions *called* in these C files.

I couldn't find that option in ctags, and cscope appears only interactive.

How can I get a list of the functions *called* in one or more C files, sent to stdout for further piping/filtering?

Comment: cscope can be used from the command line.  First use `-b` to build the refs, then use `-L -3.*` if I understand your request.

Comment: IIRC, the documentation generated by doxygen (http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) *might* contain this information, along with a **whole** lot of other information.